# Why do players leave the World Cup host nation as soon as their team is eliminated?

Tags: football, world-cup

I have observed consistently that as soon as a team is knocked out of the World Cup, they are immediately flown away from the host nation.

Why do players leave the host nation as soon as their team is eliminated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main reasons for this:

- Domestic competitions are paused for the World Cup, but will resume shortly (some of them [already have](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/63843375), in fact). Clubs want their players back, so they can re-integrate into the squad and not miss any games, and players want to turn their attention to the competition(s) that they actually *are* still competing in.
- They don't really want to stick around. As you noted in your initial draft of the question, being eliminated from the World Cup is emotionally painful, and staying to watch the teams who are left wouldn't really help with that. They'd just be sitting there thinking, "That should be us".

Comment: The second point would be improved by adding sources showing this is true - it makes logical sense, but it's just a guess as it stands now.  (The first point, though, is sufficient I think for an answer.)

Answer (score -2):

To add to F1Krazy his answer

- Players take a vacation with their family
- Players playing abroad can go home for a bit and catch up with friends/relatives

Comment: Hi; this is probably accurate, but it's not a good answer as it currently stands, just a list of things they might do with no source or logical reason beyond it being a list of things people might do anyway.  Please either improve it by adding sources showing people doing these things in this context, or remove it.  Thanks!